# change below items with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, each

I have a set of items on same column in a table each item in a row (text_item). on changing one of them, I need to change all below items for example if I changed the value of `item1` to `1` then `item2`, `item3` etc.. changes to `1`.
all the items have same name.

I worked out below code but it is not working:

```
$('input[name=textName]').change(
    $(this).nextAll('input[name=textName]').each(function(){
        $(this).val(1)
    })
);
```

I don't know why it is not working and what went wrong. any help will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? Are there errors? Does *anything* happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it this way:

```
$('input[name=textName]').change(/* you forgot this part: */ function(){
    $(this).nextAll('input[name=textName]').each(function(){
        $(this).val(1);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ch3c9cyu/)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to encapsulate the code with `function(){}` in your `.change()` event